# Beautiful Soup | How to separate multiple attrs within <a> tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a webpage to collect Image Names & their respective asset URLs and write them to a CSV in two seperate columns. I have not been able to separate attrs out of the  tags.

In BS4, I am able to run:

```
soup.find_all('a')
```

It successfully returns the below html (multiplied by the photo count on the page)

```
<a aria-label="SomeImageName" data-asset-id="10101010101" 
href="SomeWebsite">
<img alt="SomeImageName" 
src="https://SomeImageUrl"/>
</a>
```

I have tried running the following (and many other variations)

```
soup.find_all('a', attrs{"aria-label", "src"})
```

and they return

```
[]
```

Anyone know how to extract this data from the  tag and write to a CSV?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! 
You are having your requirements in two different elements i.e. `aria-label` in `a` and `src` in `img`. But luckily you have got `img` nested inside the `a` tag. So iterating will be simple.

Store the names and links in a list of dictionaries and with `DictWriter()` you can easily write them into a csv file.

```
import csv
img_data = []
for a_tag in soup.find_all('a'):
    data_dict = dict()
    data_dict['image_name'] = a_tag['aria-label']
    data_dict['url'] = a_tag.img['src']
    img_data.append(data_dict)

with open('urls.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['image_name', 'url']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in img_data:    
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: thanks for the reply! Still having an issue though- Seems its not picking up `aria-label`. Heres the error I am getting on line 4

`KeyError: 'aria-label'` Thoughts?

Comment: Seems some of your tags does not have `aria-label` attribute. you can handle by either `try except` or with the following code `data_dict['image_name'] = a_tag['aria-label'] if 'aria-label' in str(a_tag) else ''`. The later will add an empty string if the attribute is missing and the first will skip the blocks which doesn't have the attribute. P.S.: the `if else` is a one liner and you can add it just like that.

Comment: Awesome it looks like that fixed part of it, now getting the same error as in Hari's example- `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` on line containing `data_dict['url'] = a_tag.img['src']` -- I'll do some research on this error now. Do you know of a fix? ((it seems like these are some pretty common issues with BS. It's my first time using. Thanks a billion for the help!))

Comment: Just add similar if else there. But the condition must check the presence of the `img` tag there. Something like `if a_tag.img else ''`. And instead of thanking do an upvote to my answer which will motivate me to share knowledge more.

Comment: Thanks @SmashGuy I got it working. I posted an answer if you'd like to see what I ended up doing!

Comment: If it is possible for you to share the url i might help in extracting aria-label also.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, it extracts the value of src attribute of `<img>` tag which is inside the `<a>` tag that has an attribute `aria-label` and write those links to a csv file

```
## To get the value of src attribute in the <img> tag
tags = soup.find_all('a')
src=[]
for tag in tags:
    if tag.has_attr('aria-label'):
        src.append(tag.img['src'])

##writing to a csv file
with open('csvfile.csv','w') as file:
    for line in src:
        file.write(line)
        file.write('\n')
```

Or you can use the `csv` module to write the data

```
import csv
with open('csvfile1.csv', "w",newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(src)
```

Comment: [`find_all`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names) and why not use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) module?

Comment: @G_M, what is the difference between `find_all()` and `findAll()`?

Comment: @SmashGuy Link was provided... BeautifulSoup 3 vs 4

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Hari! I did however run into this error:

`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-199-9ab36d053c0c> in <module>()
      3 for tag in tags:
      4     if tag.has_attr('aria-label'):
----> 5         src.append(tag.img['src'])

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`


Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the input! I still wasn't able to pull `aria-label` and I read on some other forums this is a BS4 issue when parsing HTML.

I was, however, able to solve this quite easily using @SmashGuy solution, and pulling the alt text description versus `aria-label`.

```
img_data = []
for img_tag in soup.find_all('img'):
    data_dict = dict()
    data_dict['image_name'] = img_tag['alt']
    data_dict['image_url'] = img_tag['src']
    img_data.append(data_dict)
```

And to write to CSV...

```
with open('BCDS1.csv', 'w', newline='') as birddata:
    fieldnames = ['image_name', 'image_url']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(birddata, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for data in img_data:
        writer.writerow(data)
```

Thanks again for everyone's help! Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

for images you need to find the `<img>` tag, `<a>` is markup for links.

```
<a aria-label="SomeImageName" data-asset-id="10101010101" href="SomeWebsite">
    <img alt="SomeImageName" src="https://SomeImageUrl"/>
</a>
```

you found that image because as you can see, the link tag wraps  the image tag.

and that's not how dictionary syntax works, use `:` in `attrs={}` (see https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments)

so it's `soup.find_all('a', attrs={'css': 'value'})` instead of `soup.find_all('a', attrs{"aria-label" "SomeImageName"})`

Comment: Downvoted as the answer did not provide the appropriate solution for the question. Try understanding the questions and give answers.

Comment: i pointed out that he targeted tag <a> when he asked how to captured attribute <img>, which in means he would have missed **any other images** outside of <a> tags. There is no right appropriate solution unless targetting <a> was exactly his intention, for instance because **all** the images in the HTML file, _which was not included_, are wrapped in the <a> tag.

I understood the question properly to know that he didn't know enough BS4 & HTML.